# How to set umask for Apache on Amazon Linux 2 AMI

Tags: apache-2.4, httpd, systemd, umask, amazon-linux-2

I want to set `umask 0002` for Apache httpd so that certain files that it creates will be writable by other users.

The traditional solutions don't seem to work on Amazon Linux 2 AMI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the file `/etc/systemd/system/httpd.service.d/umask.conf` with the contents

```
[Service]
UMask=0002
```

Then reload the systemd configuration and restart the httpd service.

You can do this from within a script using:

```
mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/httpd.service.d
cat >> /etc/systemd/system/httpd.service.d/umask.conf << 'EOL'
[Service]
UMask=0002
EOL
systemctl daemon-reload
service httpd restart
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore.  Any updates?